# How to solve following SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `t1`, following is the data in that table

```
ID   DATE          INDEX
1    2015-12-13    N
1    2016-10-13    Y
1    2018-04-03    N
2    2004-12-13    N
2    2018-04-03    N
```

I have index N for ID 1 for today's date but for the same ID i already had index Y also for some other date, whereas for ID 2 for today's date we have index N and Y index was not found for that ID.

The output which i m looking for should look like this

```
ID    DATE       INDEX   Final Date
1    2018-04-03    N     2016-10-13
2    2018-04-03    N     2018-04-03
```

- output should contain only two rows as there are two different ID's date
- index should have the value for today's date only
- but final date column should contain other date if we had Y index earlier else same date will appear there

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49631232/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Also please see **[ask]**.

Comment: What if you have Y and N on the same date?

Comment: is it mysql or sql-server? both are different database products

Comment: I tried doing partition by and order by but was unable to write subqueries to get the required output

Comment: @Shawn We cannot have Y and N for the same date

Comment: @Ven SQL server

Comment: What value do you want for FinalDate if you have two rows with Y for the same ID? MAX? MIN?

Comment: Please give us a better explain of choose logic. Add more sample data where you choose Y  where data isnt today, etc.

Comment: @SeanLange we cannot have two rows with Y for same ID

Comment: Is that actual constraints in the database or application rules? Reason I ask is they are VERY different animals. I suspect application rules. But if you can post some ddl (create table statement), sample data (insert statements) and the desired output we can help. There are just too many assumptions at this point.

Comment: What if there's no row with today's date for an ID?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(ID INT, DATE DATE,[INDEX] VARCHAR(5))
INSERT into @Table values(1,'2015-12-13','N')
INSERT into @Table values(1,'2016-10-13','Y')
INSERT into @Table values(1,'2018-04-03','N')
INSERT into @Table values(2,'2004-12-13','N')
INSERT into @Table values(2,'2018-04-03','N')

SELECT id
    , CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)DATE
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN [INDEX] END)[INDEX]
    ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [INDEX] = 'Y' THEN DATE END),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))[Final Date]
FROM @Table
GROUP BY id
```

**Output:**

```
id  DATE      INDEX Final Date
1   2018-04-03  N   2016-10-13
2   2018-04-03  N   2018-04-03
```

Comment: This will only calculate the final date for today's date, even if the last 'N' date was not today.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Corrected for missed FinalDate. Now also sorts for same date Y/N and calculates for final date and not today's date.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/44100/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( ID int, dt date, idx varchar(1) ) ;
INSERT INTO t1 (ID, dt, idx) 
VALUES 
    ( 1,'2015-12-13','N')
  , ( 1,'2016-10-13','Y')
  , ( 1,'2018-04-03','N')
  , ( 2,'2004-12-13','N')
  , ( 2,'2018-04-03','N')
  , ( 3,'2018-01-03','N')
  , ( 3,'2018-01-05','Y')
  , ( 3,'2018-01-05','N')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT s1.ID, s1.dt, s1.idx--, s1.rn, t1.*
  , CASE WHEN t1.idx = 'Y' THEN t1.dt ELSE s1.dt END AS finalDate
FROM (
  SELECT ID, dt, idx
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY dt DESC, idx DESC) AS rn
  FROM t1
) s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 ON s1.ID = t1.ID
  AND t1.idx = 'Y'
WHERE s1.rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/44100/1/0)**:

```
| ID |         dt | idx |  finalDate |
|----|------------|-----|------------|
|  1 | 2018-04-03 |   N | 2016-10-13 |
|  2 | 2018-04-03 |   N | 2018-04-03 |
|  3 | 2018-01-05 |   Y | 2018-01-05 |
```

Comment: You miss `final date`

Comment: Add a `MAX(CASE WHEN idx = 'Y' THEN dt END) OVER` to get the *final date*

Comment: Corrected for finalDate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice way to do this without needing variables (replace your table name and columns):

```
select col1 id,  col2 startdate, col3 [index],
case when exists(select 1 from #temp a where a.col1=b.col1 and a.col3='y') then (select col2 from #temp a where a.col1=b.col1 and a.col3='y' )else cast(getdate() as date) end enddate
from #temp b 
where col2=cast(getdate() as date)
```